# Selecting last partition in integer partition

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to get the last partition from an integer partition.
For example:

```
IntegerPartitions[8, {3}]
```

> ```
> {{6, 1, 1}, {5, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 1}, {4, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2}}
> ```

I want to get only `{3,3 2}` or `{4,2,2}`.

How to get only one specific pair?

Comment: Use `Last`, surely. Does that not do what you want?

Comment: if by "specific pair" you mean the triplet at position `n`, try `IntegerPartitions[8, {3}][[ n ]]`. Or `IntegerPartitions[8, {3}][[- n ]]` if you want to count backwards

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basics of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. When you see good ones, please vote them up by clicking the grey triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. As you receive help, try to give it too, by *answering questions* in your area of expertise.

Comment: `Last@IntegerPartitions[8, {3}]` or `IntegerPartitions[8, {3}, All, -1]` is all you need. Be aware that your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  given that the answer is trivially found in the documentation. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Actually, if you'd bothered to read the docs, you'd have seen that `IntegerPartitions[]` takes a fourth argument…

Answer (score 3):

You want this:

```
IntegerPartitions[8, {3}, All, -1]
```

> ```
> {{3, 3, 2}}
> ```

This avoids full enumeration of all partitions, allowing e.g.:

```
IntegerPartitions[3548932, {9}, All, -1]
```

> ```
> {{394326, 394326, 394326, 394326, 394326, 394326, 394326, 394325, 394325}}
> ```

Comment: Dear Mr.Wiard, Could you help me a question if you have time now? Please see [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica) and [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SLOYn.png) Thanks a lot:) In addition [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dMbxc.png)

Comment: @ShutaoTang I am taking a break from answering questions as I have been feeling "burned out."   I don't want my participation here to become a drudgery.  Nevertheless your apparent problem seems straightforward enough so I'll try to work something up.

Comment: @Shutao I think you just need to remove the empty lists `{}` from your result?  Does this yield your desired expression?  `Partition[pts, {3, 5}, {2, 4}, {1, 1}, {}] /. {} -> Sequence[]`

Comment: Yes, @Mr.Wizard this is the desired expression that I want. THX a lot:). In additon, I aksed you this question because I known this problem can be solved by `Partition` firstly. However,I tried many times with the help of *documentation*. However, owning to I am not familiair with the advanced usage for multi-dimentional array of  `Partition`, I failed.